# Можно ли из базы вывести картинку в input file?

Tags: php, html

Когда из бд вывожу в textarea или input text, то текст выводится.

Можно ли вывести картинку из бд в input file?

На примере снизу в textarea выводится текст, а в input file не выводится

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputReview1">Отзыв</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="exampleInputReview1"><?= $review->review?></textarea>
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Фото</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="exampleInputFile" value="<?= $review->photo?>">
</div>
```

Comment: А зачем выводить картинку в input file?

Answer (score 1):

В `Input` типа `file` нельзя вставлять значения.

Если вы вставите значение в такое поле - любой современный браузер проигнорирует это, и при подтверждении формы это поле будет пустое.